# Solving first order differentials

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

How do i solve  $x(t):   \frac{dx}{dt}=x\tan(t)-\cos(t)$ ?? the struggle im finding in this and in similar issue is the seperation. This means i havent been able to get very far in this example of any other questions.

Answer (score 1):

this is linear first order
$$x'-x\tan t=-\cos t$$
$$P(t)=-\tan t$$
$$Q(t)=-\cos t$$

$$\rho =e^{\int P(t)dt}=e^{\int -\tan t dt}=e^{\log|\cos t|}=\cos t$$

$$x\rho=\int\rho P(t)dt=\int (\cos t).(-\cos t) dt+C$$
and the complete the solution

Answer (score 0):

$\textbf{hint}$

With these types of odes try manipulating the original ODE i.e.
$$
\cos (t) x' = \sin (t) x -\cos^2(t)
$$
rearrange we get
$$
\cos (t) x' - \sin (t) x = -\cos^2(t)
$$
now we have
$$
\dfrac{d}{dt}\cos (t) x = \cos(t) x' -\sin(t) x
$$

Answer (score 0):

Notice, Given first order linear D.E. $$\frac{dx}{dt}=x\tan t-\cos t$$$$\implies \frac{dx}{dt}-x\tan t=-\cos t$$
Integration factor (I.F.) $$I.F.=e^{\int -\tan t\ dt}=e^{\ln\cos t}=\cos t$$
Hence, the solution is given as $$x(\cos t)=\int \cos t\ (-\cos t)\ dt+C $$
$$x(\cos t)=-\int \cos^2 t\ dt+C $$
$$x(\cos t)=-\int \frac{1+\cos 2t}{2}\ dt+C =-\frac{1}{2}\int dt-\frac{1}{2}\int \cos 2t \ dt+C$$
$$\color{blue}{x\cos t=-\frac{1}{2}t-\frac{1}{4}\sin 2t+C}$$

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite the differential equation to

$$
\frac{dx}{dt} \cos(t) = x \sin(t) - \cos^2(t),
$$

but note that

$$
\frac{d}{dt} \left(x \cos(t)\right) = \frac{dx}{dt} \cos(t) - x \sin(t),
$$

so the differential equation can also be written as

$$
\frac{d}{dt} \left(x \cos(t)\right) = -\cos^2(t).
$$

Now by introducing a new variable $u(t)=x \cos(t)$, you can solve that by separation of variables and finally solve for $x(t)$ by using the definition for $u(t)$.